# How to use MongoDB GridFS to save and query images effectively for multiple collections in Java

Tags: java, mongodb, gridfs

I'm using java and mongodb for my project.
I want to store images in my mongodb database. I have different collections in one database.
Each collection consists of embedded objects like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2GjG.png)

My database stores owners in which the owners presents their vehicles in the different collections.
Now I want to save for every specific car an image. I have already informed myself about GridFS and I know that I can save files which are larger than 16MB. My question is how to effectively save and query the files (in my case images) with GridFS. Is it possible to "open" a particular image from GridFS which belongs to an object from the relative collection?
To make it easier to understand I will give you an example: I want the image of ford mustang gt (2015) which belongs to the first collection.

I'm not sure if my approach is even correct, so I would appreciate any other suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you include all the metadata which would exist for each entry in GridFS?

Comment: To be honest with you I dont know  which is the best way to handle the metadata.
My idea was something like this:
GridFSUploadOptions options = new GridFSUploadOptions().chunkSizeBytes(358400).metadata(new Document("name of the owner","name of the car"));

Comment: [Read the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/), and then decide which information you want to include in the `metadata` key.  This is the key which you query when you do a `find()` against GridFS.

Comment: I have thought about how to store and manage the images properly. I'm not sure if it makes sense to use metadata to find the respective image because I would use key value pairs of the path (see image) as metadata. However, as the path can be changed the metadata wouldn't be correct anymore. So, wouldn't it be easier to save the name of the collection and the path of the subdocument as a string (for ex. Vehicles1CarsCoupesFordMustangGTImage1)? If I change the path, I can also change the filename. The idea might be simple but it seems very not elegant.